# Convert String to Date in java - Time zone

Tags: java, date

I have a String, `2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-07:00`, want to convert this to Java date object. I am getting parsing error.

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-07:00");
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                 .parse("2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-0700");
```

The Z is not a literal and the timezone does not have a colon

See the examples at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If java7 is being used then `Z` can be replaced with `X` and the timezone can have a colon

Answer (score 4):

`Z` shouldn't be inside quotes. I don't think `Z` would work for your given timezone. Before Java 7, I guess there wasn't any format to parse ISO 8601 format timezone with colon in between. You should use `-0700` instead.

However, from Java 7 onwards, you have an option for parsing [ISO 8601 format timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) using `X` instead of `Z`. See javadoc for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Just use the following format:

```
// This would work from Java 7 onwards
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")    
                     .parse("2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-07:00");
```

Comment: @user2310289 Oops. Typo.

Comment: Only your answer can be compiled in Java 6 :D - great!

Comment: @robson You mean with `X`?

Comment: @user2310289 sorry, I mean your code is working (I copied/pasted your code) :-) Plus for you. X is working in Java 7 as Rohit mentioned, not Java 6. Sorry once more.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern is wrong, you should use the following:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
                        .parse("2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-07:00");
```

The 'X' indicates the Time zone in the ISO 8601 format as expressed in your `String` here: '.205-07:00'

For more information read the doc: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: do not need multiple X's

Comment: As the doc says 'ISO 8601 Time zone: The number of pattern letters designates the format for both formatting and parsing'. Link here: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use this trick to parse ISO8601 datetime format. I admit have not tried this with millisecond part within a string value maybe it gives you an extra headache. This works for Java6.

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(strDatetime);
```

If am remembering correct cal instance may not use a system-default timezone. Its initialized to the origin string value timezone. If you want instance to use system timezone you can do this conversion.

```
   long ts = cal.getTimeInMillis();
   cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTimeInMillis(ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `XXX` for the format `-07:00`, instead of `Z` and `X`.

```
   Date sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
           .parse("2013-10-07T23:59:51.205-07:00");
```

Look at the example of this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-07:00` is not a valid Time zone . The Time Zone should have this [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone), for example something like `-0800`.

Comment: Unless you're using java 7 in which `-08:00` is a valid time zone